# VBA - How to get specific value from a column

Tags: vba

**VBA**.  I want to get selected value from a column A.

ex. I only want to get value from columnA which is 
"book"

`columnA  columnB  columnC
 book     yellow    2
 pen      black     3
 book     blue      4
 bag      blue      1`

now, the output that i want is like this

```
columnA  columnB   columnC
book     yellow    2
book     blue      4
```

i have the logic but I don't how to start

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Now, I want to help you, but I would like to make you think yourself as well. So here's how I would start. Try to google the rest yourself, because that will make you a better programmer.

I would create a **range** which I'd **set** at A2 (in this case at the value "book") and **loop** it all the way down until it reaches an empty cell (the **value** of this cell is nothing). In every loop it checks (look up **if statement**) whether the value of this range is "book" (you might want to do this with **LCase** to make it case insensitive) and **copy** the required values to another worksheet.

All the relevant things you have to put in your code are in bold. You don't need loads of code for this, it should be doable for a beginning programmer. If you need more help, post the code you've written so far and we'll try to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

lngLastRow = wksht1.Range("A" & wksht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

```
rownum = 2
For Index = 2 To lngLastRow
    'Column A - AO
    'from wksht1 = "kaizen"
    outputWksht.Range("A" & rownum).Value = wksht1.Range("C" & Index).Value
    outputWksht.Range("B" & rownum).Value = wksht1.Range("D" & Index).Value
    outputWksht.Range("C" & rownum).Value = wksht1.Range("E" & Index).Value
    outputWksht.Range("D" & rownum).Value = wksht1.Range("G" & Index).Value
    outputWksht.Range("E" & rownum).Value = wksht1.Range("H" & Index).Value
```